# Are electromagnetic pulses light?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

I'm sorry if this has been asked before, I've tried researching this and I didn't get any results relevant to my question. Also, this is my first question on StackExchange, so forgive me for anything I may have unknowingly done wrong...

Electromagnetic pulses are, as I understand... uh, well, pulses. In electromagnetic fields. Now, I also understand that *light* is an electromagnetic *wave*. I'm confused about what the difference between the two is, besides one being continuous and the other being a short burst. Would an EMP not appear as an extremely brief (probably imperceivable to human eyes) flash of light? I do understand that humans can't see all wavelengths of light- I'm asking if EMPs are light at all. The reason why I'm confused is that I never see EMPs described as light.

I would greatly appreciate any help you could grant me. Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to physics SE! -NN

Comment: See this wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_pulse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All forms of electromagnetic waves are light. You cannot see it, but you would feel the effects of it.